# Seed once several tables for phpunit I testing with Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I'm coding functional tests with sqlite in memory for faster results.

Everything seems ok, but I have several tables that needs to be filled so the tests works. They are small tables, and almost never change, so I would like to seed them once on the beginning of the phpunit command only.

Is it posible???

The only thing I fought is adding: `Artisan::call('db:seed');` to `createApplication()` but this will seed once for every tests, and I don't need it..

Any Idea how should I do it?

Comment: Have you tried creating a dummy test that will call artisan::call('db:seed') and name it so it runs as the first test?

Comment: it might work, but it is not so great to do this kind of thing...

Comment: Your approach isn't the best because one test can manipulate data in a way that will break future tests, or make test dependent to each other. The proper way is to insert the data used by each test.

Comment: yes, you are probably right, but in this case, the dependency is quite simple, and this should save a lot of time for my tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use environment variable for refreshing database whenever you want. I don't know if it's the best way but it works for me.

Add variable to **.env** file

```
DB_REFRESH=true
```

and change **CeatesApplication.php** trait method:

```
   public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        if(getenv('DB_REFRESH') === 'true') {
            \Artisan::call('migrate:refresh');
            \Artisan::call('db:seed');
            putenv('DB_REFRESH=false');
        }

        return $app;
    }
```

and then try in **ExampleTest.php**

```
public function testBasicTest()
{
    $this->assertTrue(true);
}

public function testChangeDatabase()
{
    //if database changes here set variable to true
    //and it will be refreshed before the next test
    putenv("DB_REFRESH=true");
}

public function testRefresh()
{
    //you have fresh database here
}
```

Comment: Followed this one and after hours of hair pulling, the test finally succeeded! Thank you, omfg!